# Twitter OAuth for Iphone apps, twitbird

Tags: iphone, authorization, oauth

I am wondering if anyone has an idea on how did twitbird developers use oauth for allowing the user to authorize their app ?(they say that they did use OAuth)

when I was trying their app they used the username and password directly without redirection to twitter.

I searched for a solutions and there is no obvious answer because as far as I know OAuth doesnt allow the 3rd part applications to use the user's password..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter has a new OAuth method called xAuth. It takes your username and password and does a one time exchange for OAuth access tokens which are then used for normal OAuth.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-oauth-access_token-for-xAuth